# Template lite tags

Tags: php

I really searched but found nothing.

I'm new at template lite. I add my project template_lite library and I have two files.

test.php is:

```
 require("../src/class.template.php");
 $tpl = new Template_Lite;
 $tpl->assign("foo","bar");
```

and test.html is

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Document Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
          {$foo}
    </body>
</html>
```

what the wrong is output:`"{$foo}"`

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://templatelite.sourceforge.net/docs/getting.started.html) you need to set two variables:

> There are two variables that you need to set after loading Template
>   Lite: $template_dir and $compile_dir.

```
require('/path/to/class.template.php');
    $tpl = new Template_Lite;
    $tpl->compile_dir = "compiled/";
    $tpl->template_dir = "templates/";
```